# Burnitate "Power" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag **doesn't have user guidance**.  Lacking user guidance, it can be (mis) used for anything related to power without checking for suitable tags available, as is the case

Going through 52 questions in the tag and appropriately adding tags, I found the questions , mostly related to [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on), [power-options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-options), [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging), [battery-lfe](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-lfe). As such there is no value in duplicating under [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) and the fact that no user guidance has been approved since inception adds to the argument that it is redundant

I discussed this with mods in chat and seek consensus for:

- Burnitating [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag
- Making "power" a synonym for [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on) so that it is not recreated in future

**Edit:**  If you have reasons to retain the tag, please present them

Comment: Thanks to all burners for their combined powers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm one of the mods beeshyams discussed this in chat, and I've also checked some of the questions using this tag. My results where exactly the same, as was my conclusion:

- replace the [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) by one of [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on), [power-options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-options), [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging), [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life)
- if one of those "replacement tags" is already present, and none of the others fits, simply remove the [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power)
- if there are no more questions using the [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag, convert it to a synonym to [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on).

All in favor of this, raise your … ahm … mouse-pointers and upvote this answer – as I also agree with beeshyams we should have some consensus here :)

Comment: Thanks for your support and should have credited and acknowledged your suggestion in question.I have already added relevant tags to  the questions (where required) , *without deleting [tag:power] tag*.Of course, this can be reviewed. That leaves us with next two steps once we get *ayes*

Comment: I did not want to *assume* consensus and delete [tag:power] tag. I suppose mods have means of deleting the tag in one shot, whereas manual deletion would pop up 52 questions in *active questions*, merely due to tag deletion

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't go straight for it. Thanks for your preparations! AFAIK at least a mod can go straight to convert a tag into a synonym, but that would leave the "original tag" on the question (just new uses would directly be replaced with the target). Not really applicable in our case here, as not all `power` tags mean `power-on` (or are even related to it); so we'll have to do it manually anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) is a bit uninformative. I'm not yet convinced that making it a synonym for [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on) is the right thing in the long term. While a lot of existing uses of [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) are about startup, there are a lot more about the power button. If those questions start being tagged with [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on), then that tag will become as useless as [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) is now. Maybe we need a new [power-button](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-button) tag.

Comment: Regarding [tag:power-button] tag proposed,  we have [tag:power-options] tag ( with usage guidance) and [tag:buttons] tag ( *without* usage guidance ). Maybe modifying the former or creating a guidance for the latter to meet  needs of proposed tag could be an option. I may be in a minority, but feel we should make existing tags more inclusive, rather than create, given the fact people (especially new users) don't seem to read tag description (my assumption) before appending them and go by tag name or what comes up, like typing battery brings up battery-life, so add that if it fits

Comment: @beeshyams `power-options` isn't fitting here. But after a quick glance I agree on "buttons" (which is even used in a matching case), as it deals with all kind of hardware buttons (from volume rockers to headset buttons). It could use an excerpt and tag-wiki though (hint: easy place for +4 rep :)

Comment: @izzy As suggested [tag:buttons] tag description has been created to accomodate proposed [tag:power-button] tag and stands approved. Tagging relevant questions with [tag:buttons] tag can be done when "go-ahead" is given (to avoid multiple bumps into active questions)

Comment: Which brings another set of tags into the game: we also have tags for [home-button](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-button) (x 31) and [media-button](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-button) (x 5). Should they be integrated with the `buttons` tag then as well, or left stand-alone?

Comment: @beeshyams we have the [tag-cleanup](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup) tag here at meta, which can be used with questions like "calling for a general tag-cleanup" :) (I've linked it here, so you can take a look at "past tag-wars" and how they were organized)

Comment: @izzy thanks. I didn't know that and a quick look shows most of them originated by you :). So,it appears from a cursory look that tackling them on a case by case basis is the precedent. Going by that , let's get the present one closed and arrive at actionables in terms of a) main question b) merging the tags pointed out by you with "buttons" tag. +1 for "tag wars" :)

Comment: @beeshyams may I suggest opening a new Met-Q using the `tag-cleanup` tag and summing things up there? Not a good idea to do all that in comments :)

Comment: @DanHulme If I read your answer correctly, you basically agree with all parts of my answer except for the synonym power->power-on, am I reading that correctly? `buttons` wouldn't be the right target either IMHO, and not synonymizing at all will simply result in the `power` tag reappearing sooner or later. So may I suggest going the full approach as outlined by beeshyams and me, and decide about re-routing the `power` synonym another time / with another Meta-Q? I (and if I'm not wrong many others) would oppose a new `power-button` tag; see above discussion.

Comment: Maybe instead create a synonym `power-button`->`buttons` (as proposed for `home-button` and `media-button` above)?

Answer (score 2):

[power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag has been burninated!

Some analysis:

1. The tag was usually used in conjunction with:

   - Powering a device: [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on), sometimes [boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot)
   - Power consumption: [battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery), [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life)
   - Charging process and rate: [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging)
   - Power button and its behavior: [buttons](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons), [power-options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-options), *see (3)*
2. Given many different meanings, it's too ambiguous, **don't synonymize** to any tag. When someone create the tag in the future, just remove and replace it with available tags.
3. Creating [power-button](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-button) should be a reasonable choice, given that there are not too many physical/hardware [buttons](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons) on Android device, while it can also help categorizing the question in better scope.

   Possible search query to help retagging: [`power button is:q -[power-button]`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=power%20button%20is%3aq) (sorted by score, exclude questions already tagged with it). If you want to participate in retagging, please *ensure* that the question is really asking about power button issue.